# Having multiple versions of Rails installed on OS X

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, macos, rubygems

OS X 10.6 has Rails 2.2.2 installed by default.
How to upgrade to Rails 2.3.8?

Since Rails 3 is out, is it possible to have multiple versions of Rails (like 2.3.8 and 3) installed on OS X?
(For example, I could be working on two Rails projects, one is Rails 2.x and the other is Rails 3.x).

Comment: One thing to remember is that Ruby, Python, Perl and anything else installed by default in the system is expected to be at known version levels, both by the OS developers and anyone else writing system-level code. Arbitrarily changing libraries in what they consider sacred code can lead to hard to diagnose bugs because there are no integration and regression tests available. Consider changing the system's Ruby like you would changing commands in `/usr/bin` and you'll probably be safe, but understand it could go wrong too.

Comment: Use `locate *.py | grep ^/usr | grep -v /System` with the various languages' extensions to see what Apple uses. The languages aren't there as icing on the cake, they're there for specific purposes too.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use [rvm](http://rvm.beginrescueend.com/)

> RVM is a command line tool which allows us to easily install, manage and work with multiple ruby environments from interpreters to sets of gems...
>
> RVM allows users to deploy each project with its own completely self-contained and dedicated environment--from the specific version of ruby all the way down to the precise set of required gems to run the application. Having a precise set of gems also avoids the issue of version conflicts between projects, causing difficult-to-trace errors and hours of hair loss. With RVM, NO OTHER GEMS than those required are installed. This makes working with multiple complex applications where each has a long list of gem dependencies efficient. RVM allows us to easily test gem upgrades by switching to a new clean set of gems to test with while leaving our original set intact. It is flexible enough to even have a set of gems per environment or development branch--or even individual developer's taste...

Comment: agreed, this is exactly what rvm was created for. Look at gemsets for a 2.x and 3.x set of gems

Comment: Rvm is for multiple versions of Ruby and gem-environments. Not for specific gems. You could easily do this without rvm. Right?

Comment: RVM is not only for multiple versions of Ruby, it also has a feature called gemsets.  Using two gemsets, you can easily have two versions of Rails installed with no problems at all.

Comment: I think rvm is way overkill for users who don't need to manage ruby versions or gemsets at the OS level.

Comment: I must say that when I wrote this answer nearly three years ago, I was using RVM but I found it rather heavy handed. If you're writing Rails 3+ apps, I'd recommend rbenv for installing multiple rubies and straight bundler installed in vendor/bundle inside your app. This keeps things almost entirely self-contained and plays much nicer with production environments that are usually finicky with RVM in my experience.

Answer (score 7):

I wouldn't bother with gemsets myself just do as other people have mentioned:

```
gem install -v=2.3.8 rails
```

and then to use:

```
rails _2.3.8_ new rails app
```

Note that this _versionnumber_ thing is a standard way of specifying a version of any rubygems installed executable.

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
gem install -v=2.3.8 rails
```

where -v=[version number you want to install]

Then

```
list gem rails
```

In your config/environment.rb you can state which version of Rails you want to use.

Answer (score 1):

To upgrade your OS version of the rails gem:

```
sudo gem install rails --version 2.3.8
```

While you're at it, you can also upgrade your OS rubygems system itself, overwriting the binary that OS X comes with. This might seem kind of hacky, but it's a stable thing that everyone does.

```
sudo gem install rubygems-update
sudo update_rubygems
```

Regarding managing rails versions in your projects, if your only needs are:

1. Specifying the version of rails that you want on a rails project
2. Specifying different versions of rails and/or other gems in each of multiple rails projects

Then rvm is overkill. The only thing you need, and what is also a complete and utter pleasure to work with, is [Bundler](http://gembundler.com/). Bundler is like Software Update for your rails project. In fact, Rails 3 comes with Bundler by default, you just have to list the gems you need in Gemfile and it takes care of the rest. You don't need to worry about which versions of your gems are installed in the OS.

(You do however need the appropriate version of the rails gem installed in the OS in order to generate the rails project in the first place)

Answer (score 0):

http://rubygems.org/

It's all you need =)